# Open new UIViewController when clicking on UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a simple table view that when I click on the cell, I want it to open a new UIViewController. Currently I have it so that it goes to a particular View Controller now, but it seems as if every cell leads to the same View Controller. I want each one to go to a different one. Here is my attempt:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    var indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
    let navController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ChatController") as UINavigationController

    navController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = true
    let chatController = navController.viewControllers.first as ChatController
    chatController.currentUserName = self.firstName + " " + self.lastName
    chatController.chatWith = chatNames[indexPath!.row]
    chatController.currentUserObjectID = self.objectID
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to work as I get an error saying `Storyboard doesn't contain a view controller with identifier 'ChatController''`. If it helps, the segue first goes through a navigation controller then to the desired view controller.

Answer (score 1):

In the UITableViewDelegate method `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:kSegueIdentifier sender:self];`

And, according to the indexPath you can set a different value that will be passed to your next view controller through the method `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: I don't seem to have a `kSegueIdentifier` method when I call `performSegueWithIdentifier` method.

Comment: KSegueIdentifier is not a method, it's the name of your segue in the storyboard.